# Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` using with meterial ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**i got this error while working with mui on react anyone can answer this**
i want to create password feild with show and hide functions

```
             <FormControl variant="filled">
                  <InputLabel htmlFor="conpassword">
                    confrom password
                  </InputLabel>
                  <FilledInput
                    id="conpassword"
                    type={passShow ? "text" : "password"}
                    value={formValues.conpassword}
                    onChange={handelChange}
                    onBlur={_onBlur}
                    error={errors.conpassword ? true : false}
                    endAdornment={
                      <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <IconButton
                          onClick={(e) => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            setPassShow(!passShow);
                          }}
                          edge="end"
                        >
                          {passShow ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                        </IconButton>
                      </InputAdornment>
                    }
                  />
                  <span className="helper">{errors.conpassword}</span>
                </FormControl>
```

Comment: answer what? ... you did not ask a question ... `i want to ...` is not a question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.